# Using double percentage in runtime.exe doesn't pass the parameters

Tags: java, user-interface

Hei guys, I'm having some troubles with % ...

So here's the code:

```
   String random = "%RANDOM%";
       if (RadioButton1.isSelected()){
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(AppLocation+"MyApp.exe -MyApp_Session "+random);
[....]
```

As you can see I'm trying to run MyApp.exe with parameters, but because of %RANDOM% it doesn't the the parameter. Also keep in mind that this is a button action performed.

PS: AppLocation is where my exe is and the string i made to try out, it doesn't work if i place the %RANDOM% on Runtime. Also to be noted i tried with ProccesBuilder same result...

How i can make this work ?

Comment: is AppLocation a variable? Read about naming conventions in java first.

Comment: AppLocation is the path where MyApp.exe is placed, but not that's the problem. The application runs, even with other parameters but when i try to start a random session using %RANDOM% in parameters it doesn't read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked the code and change the %RANDOM% into a static int i; which after a button event adds i++;
also this could be done by replacing the %RANDOM% windows variable as any random int place as code in the project.
Thanks for the answer guys, it made me rethink the big picture.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape percentage sign `%` as`%%`.

```
String random = "%%RANDOM%%";
```

Another approach could be:

```
String random = "\"%RANDOM%\"";
```

Comment: Omfg, I'm such a noob. Thx mate I'll try that as soon as I get back to work.

Comment: @Kimmyshor remember to mark it as an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Kimmyshor maybe just the first percentage should be escaped with as `%%`

Comment: @Kimmyshor another approach use `\%`

Comment: The problem is with your operating system interpreting `%RANDOM%` as `(int)R`th command line argument.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by giving the random string an actual random number directly from application.